# Hide border on table where no cell exists in Firefox and border-collapse: collapse;

Tags: html, css, firefox

Given the following HTML page a horizontal line appears at the top of the table where the 1st row would have a 2nd and 3rd cell (if they were defined).

```
<html>
<head>
<Title>Test Page</Title>

<style type="text/css">
table {
    margin:10px 0 10px 0;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 0;
}

td {
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding:5px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Test Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sub Title</td>
            <td>Sub Title</td>
            <td>Sub Title</td>
        </tr>
    <table>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the line (highlighted below) removed by modifying CSS only. This line appears in Firefox but not IE6.

[image: Example Image]

Note that I cannot modify the HTML in any way as this is generated by a third party system (the example above is simply to highlight the issue). This third-party system only allows me to modify the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get it to render without the top border in Firefox:

```
table, td {
    border: 1px #CCC;
}

table {
    margin: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-style: none none solid solid;
}

* html table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border-style: solid solid none none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

It also works fine in IE7 for me. If it breaks in IE6, use conditional comments or css hacks to revert it to the state it was in your own code for IE6 only.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Your third party tool is generating bad/invalid markup which will give you a very large browser compatibility/css headache, if it is at all feasible, replace it or generate the html yourself**

Technically speaking the first row should be marked up as

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Test Title</td>
    </tr>
```

So I don't think you can acheive that using tables.

A css tip

```
margin: 10px 0;
```

Puts 10px at the top and bottom and 0 on the left and right

Answer (score 0):

The [empty-cells](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html#emptycells) property may help you in this case.

```
table {
  empty-cells:hide;
}
```

Then again, maybe not. Can you also explicitly turn off the border of the table rows?

Answer (score 0):

Is using javascript an option? You could inject a non breaking space into the cell, that should draw the border.

Comment: I think the question is asking how to hide the border rather than draw it.

Comment: Afraid not, this is a third-party product to which I have limited access only to modify CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this problem that really works. I found this out after sooo long

The problem is with tbody tag.

Check the solution here:
http://www.dashplanet.com/firefox-displaying-border-top-of-table-how-to-hide-that-1px-top-border-table

Comment: Hey Abdullah, I just tried this with the example in the question and Firefox 3.1 Beta 3 but the line is still visible?

Comment: can you tell me the url of your site. Also What css code did you put. This thing really works, maybe you are missing something.

Answer (score -1):

From [Firefox Colspan Border-COllapse Bug](http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Firefox_Colspan_Border-Collapse_Bug):

> The obvious workaround is to just set
>   the colspan before the DOM has
>   finished loading, or at minimum,
>   before the table has finished
>   rendering. However, this requires that
>   we clutter our otherwise clean HTML
>   with inline  tags, or have
>   prior knowledge of the number of
>   columns at the HTML generation stage.
>
> I hope to find a more elegant
>   "non-invasive JavaScript" solution in
>   the future, but at the current time I
>   don't know of one. Simply setting the
>   table's "display" style to "none" and
>   then re-setting it back to "block" did
>   not do the trick.